# setTimeout does not wait for a second

Tags: javascript

setTimeout doesnt wait for a second(1000ms)

```
function simpleFunction(FFF) {
    const b = FFF + 1;
    console.log(b);
    setTimeout(simpleFunction(b), 1000);
};

simpleFunction(i);
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEp9Z.png) after <1 second I started the program

Answer (score 2):

You're directly calling the function `simpleFunction(b)` you should give it a function instead `() => simpleFunction(b)`

```js
function simpleFunction(FFF) {
    const b = FFF + 1;
    console.log(b);
    setTimeout(() => simpleFunction(b), 1000);
};

simpleFunction(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the *result* of calling `simpleFunction` to the timeout not the function itself.

If you need to pass in an argument to the function that the timeout calls [you can add that separately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#parameters).

```js
function simpleFunction(i) {
  const b = i + 1;
  console.log(b);
  setTimeout(simpleFunction, 1000, b);
};

simpleFunction(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`simpleFunction(b)` calls function *(instantly - because of `()`)* but [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) expects function to-be called. You can wrap first argument into the another function or use [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

Example:

```js
function simpleFunction(FFF) {
    const b = FFF + 1;
    console.log(b);
    setTimeout(function() {
      simpleFunction(b)
    }, 1000);
};

simpleFunction(1);
```

You can read more about `setTimeout()` and see more examples at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).